# How to make text and image responsive?

Tags: html, css, viewport, squarespace

I am working on this website in SquareSpace, and I know how to layer images on top of one another and make them responsive, but I have been unsuccessful with text. I want this text to adjust to screen size along with the heart image.

I know that using "vh, vw, vmin, vmax" adjusts the size accordingly, BUT, when I use the viewport units, it's almost as if the sizing decreases at twice the rate of the rest of the content on the page.

Here is what I have (lacking squarespace set CSS styles of course):

```css
<style>
  .kppr
  {
    margin-top: -8%;
    margin-left: 8%;
  }
  .kppr p
  {
    color: #89d4e8;
    font-size: 400%;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" class="kppr">
  <p>
    kids play &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspparents relax
  </p>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 42%; left: 40.5%;" class="heart">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bed56ee4b04fdc6e0dd0d8/t/5759e5882b8ddea12fed577b/1465509256880/STL-Home-Heart.png" alt="Kids play, parents relax"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried media queries ?

Comment: I want to, but I really don't understand how to implement them. I know what they are, but how to use them is something I'm struggling with a little. Do you have any good resources? (other than a google search) lol

Comment: I believe that this will be all you need to go through, I learned them from this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries